# Как настроить инфраструктуру приложений angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Здравствуйте. Меня интересует, как построить архитектуру приложения на angularjs, чтобы оно было масштабиремым.

Главные требования:

- Одностраничность - все должно быть через хэшроутинг
- Вложенность представлений, все должно быть построено каким-то вложенными контролами, которые собираются в целостные страницы.
- Бэкенд на asp.net mvc webapi, который возвращает/обрабатывает данные
- динамическая подгрузка скриптов/стилей

Я более-менее изучил ангуляр, но как-то все кирпичики не выстраиваются в хорошо спроектированну схему. Буду очень признателен, если вы посоветуете что-то дельное. Большое всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вам нужна структура директорий, то Yeoman создаст для Вас дерево директорий, если это не то что Вам нужно и вы разобрались с angularjs, то я не понял вопроса, что же Вам не хватает?

**Обновление**

кому она нужна эта ленивая подгрузка если в конце концов создается один большой файл который и деплоится?

**Обновление**

один файл лучше, чем 30 маленьких.

**Обновление**

Нет, это не мое личное предпочтение. Это связано с тем, как браузер загружает ресурсы страницы. Это не только джаваскрипт, но и  стили и графика объединяется в спрайты. Может я Вас удивлю, но есть масса инструментов, которые делают эти вещи и ими нужно пользоваться!
По requrejs - это отдельный вопрос, но отвечу: он облегчает жизнь при разработке. Это искореняет проблему, когда jquery, например, загрузился после плагина, который его требует. А также, не нужно прописывать все url скриптов, которые требуются в HTML. Все в одном месте, удобно. Ну есть еще масса других полезностей, которые он дает.

Comment: Самое главное, это ленивая погрузка скриптов
\

Comment: С чего вы взяли? И чем это оправдано?

Comment: Это для меня как откровение. 
Я всегда думал, что правильнее загружать скрипты по мере их надобности, чем в одночасье все.
А все таки, это общепринятая тактика или это лично ваше предпочтение?
И это касается также стилей?

Comment: Может я Вас удивлю, но есть масса инструментов, которые делают эти вещи и ими нужно пользоваться!

Об этом я знал, но я думал, что это нужно для объединения всех скриптов в пределах страницы, а не абсолютно всех скриптов приложения.

Comment: И зачем тогда нужен requirejs и почему он такой популярный?